# XCode and RubyMotion - rake spec - permission error

Tags: xcode, rspec, rubymotion

I am trying to get a RubyMotion setup on my Mac (High Sierra) to run.

Everything worked great until i tried to implement testing. I can get the iPhone simulator to run and see my app on my screen when i run `rake`.

RubyMotion generates a default spec file `spec/main_spec.rb` and whenever i try to run `rake spec` from a newly created projekt (motion create Project) i get the following error:

```
Cannot write into the `/Users/bruger/Library/RubyMotion/build' directory, please remove or check permissions and try again.
```

The strange thing is: **there is no such folder in the RubyMotion folder** and the other folder is read, write and execute for the owner (me).

When i look at [others example](http://rubymotion-tutorial.com/8-testing/) with a succesfull test run, i can see that their code is called from the current folder like this:

```
Build ./some_path
Compile ./some_other_path
Link ./some_third_path
```

If i run the same command with `--trace` i get this output:

```
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke spec:simulator (first_time)
** Execute spec:simulator
** Invoke simulator (first_time)
** Execute simulator
** Invoke build:simulator (first_time)
** Execute build:simulator
rm -f ./build/iPhoneSimulator-11.3-Development/APP_spec.app/Info.plist
Cannot write into the `/Users/bruger/Library/RubyMotion/build' directory, please remove or check permissions and try again.
```

So it is trying to delete Info.plist from a path based on the current folder and then get a permission error in a totally different folder?

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps to help diagnose your issue:

1. Ensure that you have the latest version of Xcode installed, and that Xcode was started, and all it's components were installed.
2. `sudo motion update` which will ensure you have the latest version of RubyMotion, templates etc.
3. Create a new project from scratch, and run `rake spec`

Also note that the RubyMotion community is most active on Slack, and you will get answers there faster.  You can join at https://motioneers.herokuapp.com

Comment: Thank you for your help @wndxlori, but i decided to go for plain Swift. :)